# Smooth transition (optical effect) between uitabpanels in Matlab

Tags: user-interface, function, matlab, uicontrol

I have designed a group of three uitabpanels objects.

```
  htab = uitabgroup('v0');
  th1 = uitab('v0',htab,'title','Panel 1','ButtonDownFcn',...
      @th1_ButtonDownFcn);
  th2 = uitab('v0',htab,'title','Panel 2','ButtonDownFcn',...
      @th2_ButtonDownFcn);
  th3 = uitab('v0',htab,'title','Panel 3','ButtonDownFcn',...
      @th3_ButtonDownFcn);
```

My intention is having a smooth transition between them when I change the selected uipanel through the mouse click. I pretend to achieve it changing the 'Visible' property of the elements contained inside them using the ButtonDownFcn function ( I got this idea based on  the description section of [this page](http://bit.ly/kAxsHc)).

```
    set(handles.th2,'Visible','off');
    set(handles.th3,'Visible','off');
...
  function th1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata)
  handles = guidata(fh);
  set(handles.th1,'Visible','on');
  set(handles.th2,'Visible','off');
  set(handles.th3,'Visible','off'); 
  guidata(fh,handles);
  end

  function th2_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata)
  handles = guidata(fh);
  set(handles.th1,'Visible','off');
  set(handles.th2,'Visible','on'); 
  set(handles.th3,'Visible','off');
  guidata(fh,handles);
  end

  function th3_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata)
  handles = guidata(fh);
  set(handles.th1,'Visible','off');
  set(handles.th2,'Visible','off');
  set(handles.th3,'Visible','on');
  guidata(fh,handles);      
  end
```

where

fh: handle of the figure where they are contained the uitabpanels.

handles.th1, handles.th2, handles.th3: handles of the elements contained into each uitabpanel respectively.

However, it has not worked (I click on each one of uitabpanel's tabs and the visibility of them do not change) and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, the ButtonDownFcn and SelectionChangeFcn functions of an UITAB are already active when you click in the tab´s label. So it is not possible to achieve the desired target (smooth optical transition) because the obtained result (modifying the mentioned functions) is the same that doing nothing.